# How do I submit a form in my 'popup.html' on chrome extentions

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to submit a form on my popup html, on a chrome extension. When I submit the form, a function is called. However, the function is not being called. 
Should I use a button instead of a form?

This is the HTML for the form:

```
<html>

<body>

    <script src="contentScript.js">
    </script>

    <form name="myForm" onSubmit="form()">
        Product: <input type="text" name="product" id="product"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

This is the contentScript.js:

```
function form(){
    var product = document.getElementById('product').value;
    alert(product);
};
```

Are there any mistakes??

Thanks

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The code

```
<script>
  function myForm() {
    var product = document.getElementById('product').value;
    alert(product);
    return false;
  }
</script>
<form onsubmit="return myForm();">
  Product: <input type="text" name="product" id="product"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

would work just fine, the thing you are missing is that your function is maybe not find, but you don't prevent the submit to happen, you should always return false to the event "onsubmit" to prevent the form being submitted.

Note: you can't put inline scripts in chrome extensions anymore but you could back then.

Comment: Thanks Tomisol. The code you have put works if I am running it as a regular HTML. However, when I run it as a Chrome Extension popup HTML, the code still doesn't work. Do you know if Chrome Extension popup HTML's work in a different way?

Comment: do you have some errors in your console or anything to debug ? Try to launch the function myForm() in another place of your html, like a trigger on a button, to see if it can find the function myForm(). If not, then the problem comes from your .js file which doesn't load

Answer (score -3):

```
function form(){
    var product = document.getElementById('product').value;
    alert('your some statment there');
return false;
};
```

and make sure your are also return true at the end of main alert statment